# Adding alt+enter (excel linefeed) in tsql code

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, t-sql, excel

I'm trying to create a script to return concat lines from the DB and with c# populate an excel file with the text.

I've managed every thing, just can't find a solution for the line feed...

Tried char(10)+char(13) and many other.

I know that in excel if one want to add new line, he show use the alt+enter. is there are code of that to add to my tsql script to get the linefeed in the excel file?

Thank you,
Erez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem what using 
 in the tsql and decoding it in the c#, as i am creating a html table from the DataSet and then converting the html table into excel stylesheet.

SQL:

```
SELECT br_in.BIText + '<br>'
```

C#:

```
StrReport.Append("<td>" + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ds.Tables[k].Rows[i][j].ToString()) + "</td>");
```

This is the only thing that worked in my case and it even make sense if you think about it....

Thank you,
Erez

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problems, but mine is a copy-and-paste from the SQL Server Management Studio results window into an Excel file.  It's the same issue, just more direct.

For those folks that don't understand the problem, here's a repro.  Run the following in SSMS and copy-and-paste the results into Excel.  Set the cell to wrap text.

```
SELECT 'Hello' + CHAR(10) + 'World'
```

You'll see Hello on one cell and World on the cell below it.  What we're trying to see is

```
Hello
World
```

in one cell with a line break.

My solution was to surround the result in quotes.  There are several ways to do this.  I found this to look the cleanest:

```
SELECT QUOTENAME('Hello' + CHAR(10) + 'World', '"')
```

The result is "Hello World" in the SSMS results window.  But when pasted into Excel and the cell set with wrap text, I would get the desired result.

Comment: Note that QUOTENAME has some important restrictions, including only being able to handle strings of length 128 characters.  For longer strings, you can surround your string with CHAR(34), which is the double quote character.

`select char(34) + 'Hello' + char(10) + 'World' + char(34)`

Answer (score 0):

Cr+Lf is actually 13+10 rather than 10+13.

If that does not work, a single char(10) will.

Comment: Thank you Alex, but non of that worked... tried char(10)+char(13), char(13)+char(10),char(10),'\n\r',<br/>..... nothing worked   The problem is that in Excel newline inside a cell is alt+enter and char(10) is only linefeed 10+13 is enter in windows..... to work in excel i need alt+enter.... check in excel :-) 10x, erez

Comment: If I copy a cell with AAA{alt+enter}BBB into notepad the new line character is char(10); if I copy it back into a different cell I get 2 lines as expected (range("A1").value="A" & chr(10) & "B" works too) How are you creating the excel file?

Comment: IN tsql: declare \@newLineChar as char(2)set \@newLineChar = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) and then adding concating the texts and line feeds    \ is just for excaping for the at sign..... not part of the code

Comment: @Erez - Alex provided the solution: use a single LF which is `Char(10)`. It should be noted that you will also need to enable WrapText on the cells in question to see the line wrapping.

Comment: Thank you thomas, and as i said, tried that before, and also with the text wrap.... and still didn't work.... I'm not trying to be defecault, tried every thing i know or on the web before i've asked... The problem is with the translate to excel....In every other format every solution works just fine....

Comment: What are you doing with the results of the query you execute?

Answer (score 0):

This was the only way I could get it to work

SQL: select '="Hello"&CHAR(10)&"World"'

In Excel I also had to set the cell with wrap text.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked with following

string text = String.Format("\"{0}\"", text);

by setting your test to this format it will create alt+Enter in Excel.